# Enums can't be instantiated

Tags: flutter, dart

So I don't know how to explain this problem , but it has to do with the flutter custom Tabs and the deprecations. after running this code I get an error:

```
Future openLinkWithCustomTab(BuildContext context, String url) async {
    try {
      await FlutterWebBrowser.openWebPage(
        url: url,
        customTabsOptions: CustomTabsOptions(
          colorScheme: context.read<ThemeBloc>().darkTheme!
              ? CustomTabsColorScheme.dark
              : CustomTabsColorScheme.light,
          shareState: const CustomTabsShareState.enabled(),
          instantAppsEnabled: true,
          showTitle: true,
          urlBarHidingEnabled: true,
        ),
        safariVCOptions: const SafariViewControllerOptions(
          barCollapsingEnabled: true,
          dismissButtonStyle: SafariViewControllerDismissButtonStyle.close,
          modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance: true,
        ),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      openToast1(context, 'Cant launch the url');
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

this is the error:
lib/services/app_service.dart:66:29: Error: Enums can't be instantiated.
shareState: const CustomTabsShareState.enabled(),
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'E:\Flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1151
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'E:\Flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: Are you sure `CustomTabsShareState` have named constructor `enabled`? Based on this package API documentation this class doesn't have this constructor https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_web_browser/latest/flutter_web_browser/CustomTabsShareState.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `const CustomTabsShareState.enabled()` with `CustomTabsShareState.enabled`.

I can not find `enabled` definition in `CustomTabsShareState`:
[image: CustomTabsShareState]

So maybe you are using the wrong one. Try to change to `CustomTabsShareState.on`.

Refer to [Enumerated types](https://dart.dev/language/enum) for more info.